# Mongodb update an object in multi nested array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, nested

I have a document in mongodb with 2 level deep nested array of objects that I need to update, something like this.

```
{
  "id":12362,
  "onGoing":[
    {
      "id":14597,
      "offers":[
        {
          "id":56897,
          "status":"validated"
        },
        {
          "id":86127,
          "status":"validated"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id":89451,
      "offers":[
        {
          "id":12235,
          "status":"validated"
        },
        {
          "id":56457,
          "status":"validated"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to update all offers matching with their id.

I have tried to update like

```
db.repairJobs.update({
  "onGoing.offers":{
    $elemMatch:{
      _id:{
        $in:[
          '56897', '56457'
        ]
      }
    }
  }
},
{
  $set:{
    "ongoing.offers.$.status":"ACCEPTED"
  }
});
```

But getting the error: cannot use the part (ongoing of ongoing.offers.0.status) to traverse the element ({ongoing: [ { _id: null, ...

Are there any ways to update, the solution need to be compatible with spring Data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to update documents two level deep in MongoDB. I stumbled upon this JIRA item. I don't think there's a way to use multiple `$` operators in update operations.

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831

I am not aware of any workarounds based on your current schema but I would recommend you to let's say, split your each of your onGoing arrays into different documents.

Comment: Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

You can use array filters to do this

[Update Nested Arrays in Conjunction with $[]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#up._S_[%3Cidentifier%3E])

as for your question, my solution is

```
db.repairJobs.update(
{},
{
  $set: {
    "onGoing.$[].offers.$[elem].status": "ACCEPTED"
  }
},
{ 
  arrayFilters: [{ "elem.id": {$in: [56897, 56457]} }],
  multi: true 
});
```